# Syntax Error Label Expression Debug

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, syntaxerror

I'm attempting to debug a code for a conditional label expression. The code is based on one i have previously used and did not have any issues. The python code is as follows.

```
def FindLabel ( [TF], [INV_1], [DIR_1], [INV_2], [DIR_2], [INV_3], [DIR_3], [INV_4], [DIR_4], [INV_5], [DIR_5], [INV_6], [DIR_6] ):
  return def FindLabel ( [TF], [INV_1], [DIR_1], [INV_2], [DIR_2], [INV_3], [DIR_3], [INV_4], [DIR_4], [INV_5], [DIR_5], [INV_6], [DIR_6]):
  myLabel = "TF  {0}".format([TF])
  if not [INV_1] is None:
myLabel += "\nINV  {0}".format([INV_1]) & [DIR_1]
  if not [INV_2] is None:
myLabel += "\nINV  {0}".format([INV_2]) & [DIR_2]
  if not [INV_3] is None:
myLabel += "\nINV   {0}".format([INV_3]) & [DIR_3]
  if not [INV_4] is None:
myLabel += "\nINV   {0}".format([INV_4]) & [DIR_4]
  if not [INV_5] is None:
myLabel += "\nINV   {0}".format([INV_5]) & [DIR_5]
 if not [INV_6] is None:
myLabel += "\nINV   {0}".format([INV_6]) & [DIR_6]
  return myLabel
```

Where TF, INV_1, INV_2, INV_3, INV_4, INV_5, and INV_6 are numbers, and DIR_1, DIR_2, DIR_3, DIR_4, DIR_5, and DIR_6 are text, all have the potential to be null. When I click "OK" arcgis returns the following error

```
The expression contains an error.   
Modify the expression and try again.  
Error 0 on line 0.   
Syntaxerror: invalid syntax (<string>, line 2).
```

Coding is far from my strong suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code.  The error message is referring to the first issue it found - if you that issue you'd get an error for the next.  I'll try to outline them all for you here (hopefully I don't miss any).

1. Your second line shouldn't be there.  Remove this line

   ```
   return def FindLabel ( [TF], [INV_1], [DIR_1], [INV_2], [DIR_2], [INV_3], [DIR_3], [INV_4], [DIR_4], [INV_5], [DIR_5], [INV_6], [DIR_6]):
   ```
2. Your indentation is messed up.  Python is very particular about indentation, so be sure it's correct.

   This is incorrect:

   ```
       if not [INV_1] is None:
   myLabel += "\nINV  {0}".format([INV_1]) & [DIR_1]
   ```

   As your `myLabel += ...` is part of the `if` block, you need to indent the second line further than the first line

   ```
       if not [INV_1] is None:
           myLabel += "\nINV  {0}".format([INV_1]) & [DIR_1]
   ```

   Additionally, the line `if not [INV_6] is None:` is not indented far enough - it should line up with all the other `if` lines.
3. I'm unsure what you're trying to do with the `&` in `"\nINV  {0}".format([INV_1]) & [DIR_1]`.  As far as I know, the ampersand in python is not used with text (see Stack Overflow Q&A [What does & mean in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556206/what-does-mean-in-python)).
   It appears that you are trying to concatenate the two field values together - if so, put the `[DIR_1]` into your string format as well - something like this

   ```
   if not [INV_1] is None:
       myLabel += "\nINV {0}{1}".format([INV_1], [DIR_1])
   ```
4. While not an issue that would cause an error, this is tidier and easier to read.  Instead of `if not [INV_1] is None:`, use `if [INV_1]:`.  Basically you're saying "if INV_1 isn't false" which is the same as saying "if INV_1 is true"

   ```
   if [INV_1]:
       myLabel += "\nINV {0}{1}".format([INV_1], [DIR_1])
   ```

I think the following update to your script should work better

```
def FindLabel ([TF], [INV_1], [DIR_1], [INV_2], [DIR_2], [INV_3], [DIR_3], [INV_4], [DIR_4], [INV_5], [DIR_5], [INV_6], [DIR_6]):
    myLabel = "TF {0}".format([TF])
    if [INV_1]:
        myLabel += "\nINV {0}{1}".format([INV_1], [DIR_1])
    if [INV_2]:
        myLabel += "\nINV {0}{1}".format([INV_2], [DIR_2])
    if [INV_3]:
        myLabel += "\nINV {0}{1}".format([INV_3], [DIR_3])
    if [INV_4]:
        myLabel += "\nINV {0}{1}".format([INV_4], [DIR_4])
    if [INV_5]:
        myLabel += "\nINV {0}{1}".format([INV_5], [DIR_5])
    if [INV_6]:
        myLabel += "\nINV {0}{1}".format([INV_6], [DIR_6])
    return myLabel
```